# typedef redefination issue in iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, typedef

I am using a third party library (https://github.com/zhang28602/ZZYQRCode) for my project. When I indergrated it into my project it started throwing the following error: Typedef redefinition with different types ('void (^)(NSString *__strong)' vs 'void (^)(__strong id, NSURLResponse *__strong)')

for the following line of code: typedef void(^SuccessBlock)(NSString *reuslt);

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are getting the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That project has defined a global typedef in its public header using a very generic name (`SuccessBlock`). You likely have defined `SuccessBlock` in another way somewhere else in your program.

If possible, have the developer use prefixes on their names. This should have been `ZZYSuccessBlock`. Alternately, rename the other instance of `SuccessBlock`.

If that's not possible, try to ensure that no part of your system imports both `ZZYQRCode.h` and whatever .h file defines the other version of it.